# How to restart twisted.trial._dist.disttria.DistTrialRunner?

Tags: python, twisted

I try to use `twisted.trial._dist.disttrial.DistTrialRunner` as a runner, after some cases fail I want to re-run the fail cases, but it's not restart and get an error:

```
from twisted.trial._dist.disttrial import DistTrialRunner as Runner
runnerArgs = ({'workerNumber': 3, 'workerArguments': []})

for _ in range(3):
    RetCode, FailCases = Runner(**runnerArgs).run(suite)
    if RetCode == 0:
        exit(RetCode)
    else:
        suite = FailCases
exit(RetCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `runAsync` instead of `run`:

```
from twisted.trial._dist.disttrial import DistTrialRunner as Runner
runnerArgs = ({'workerNumber': 3, 'workerArguments': []})

async def runThreeTimes():
    runner = Runner(**runnerArgs)
    for _ in range(3):
        result = await runner.runAsync(suite)
        if result.wasSuccessful():
            exit(0)
        else:
            suite = compute_failures_from_result(result)
    exit(1)

# Run runThreeTimes, perhaps using Deferred.fromCoroutine
# Run the reactor, perhaps just by importing it and calling run() on it
```

This still requires an implementation of `compute_failures_from_result` which I've omitted because it's not obviously possible using the `TestResult` interface.  However, if you supply an alternate `reporterFactory` to `DistTrialRunner` then you can implement one that does a better job of exposing successes and failures and probably extract the information from that.